# AJAX request: Not enough or too many segments

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to do a POST request with AJAX and I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Not enough or too many segments
```

I have this function to send AJAX request:

```
function sendAjaxRequest(type, url, params, callback, returnType = 'json') {

    var token = token_admin;

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: type,
        data: params,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            /* Authorization header */
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "BEARER " + token);
            // xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mobile", "false");
        },
        dataType: returnType,
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
    request.done(function(res) {
        callback(res);
    });
    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.error(jqXHR);
        callback({ err: true, message: "Request failed: " + textStatus });
    });

}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
var hostAPI = 'server_url';
var token_admin = 'some_token';

var params = {
    "criteria": {
        "lang.es_es.verb.parent": "abandonar"
    }
}

sendAjaxRequest("POST", hostAPI + 'words/getByCriteria', JSON.stringify(params), function(response) {
        console.log("------------");
        console.log(response);
        console.log("------------");
});
```

But it's always returning me this error, the most weird thing is that I tested this webservice in Insomnia like this:

```
{
    "criteria": {
            "lang.es_es.verb.parent": "abandonar"
    }
}
```

And it returns all data properly. I'm pretty new with AJAX and I have no idea of what's happening here, why it works in Insomnia and not with Javascript AJAX? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: I'm guessing that its the binding in the controller. but you say it works separately , how did you test?, otherwise it looks good to me.

Comment: hey maybe its JSON.stringify() remove that... you are doing a POST.... make your controller action is good to receive a POST

Comment: I tested it with Insomnia, using the same action (POST), the same link, content type (application/json) and token/authorization (with BEARER in capital letters). I think it's the same in both parts, but by some reason in Javascript doesn't work. I removed JSON.stringify() and now I'm receiving a different error:

"Unexpected token at parse"

It seems that there's a problem with my token, but I don't know why it only happens in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually comes when your [JWT token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) is malformed or invalid. Please note that you are passing it in headers

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "BEARER " + token);
```

Please ensure that the token is valid, and the API is capable of accepting it. Also, please try to change `BEARER` to `Bearer`. The latter can be a cause if the API is not ignoring the case while checking for the header value.

Comment: My token should be valid because I'm using the same that I'm using in Insomnia (and with BEARER in capital letters), but you're right that it has to be something related because now I removed JSON.stringify() and now I'm receiving a different error: "Unexpected token at parse". Maybe am I sending it the wrong way? I tried to write "Bearer" like you said, but the error persist.